# Is there a way to have Outlook VSTO read a text file?

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins

I am using the language c#. I got Outlook to run through VSTO, but cannot seem to have the text file I want Outlook to read run correctly. The text file consists a list of names, which I want to have it automatically look up through Outlook to give me a statement of true or false if there is a match for the name in Outlook from the textfile. I want it to read the text file by row. Here is my code so far:

```
namespace OutlookAddIn1
{
    public partial class ThisAddIn
    {
        private static int Main(string[] args)


        {

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("hello");
            Console.WriteLine("test");
            string filePath = @"C:\Users\Desktop\QC\User_.txt"; 
            string filePath2 = @"C:\Users\Documents\QC\userlist.txt";
            List<string> lines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath).ToList();
            Console.WriteLine(lines);
            foreach (string line in lines)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(line);
            }
            lines.Add("True");

            List<string> list = new List<string>();
            string inSystem = "";
            lines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath).ToList();
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(filePath)) ;
            string OutLook_Username_Output = "";
            foreach (string line in lines)
            {
                if (line.Equals(OutLook_Username_Output))
                {
                    inSystem += "true" + Environment.NewLine;
                }
                else
                {
                    inSystem += "false" + Environment.NewLine;
                }
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("true");
                Console.WriteLine(line);
                for (int i = 0; i < lines.Count; i++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(lines[i] + ":" + inSystem[i]);
                }
                

             

                File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\059974\Documents\QC\userlist.txt",inSystem );
                return 0;

            }



             private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
                        {
                        }

                        private void ThisAddIn_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
                        {
                            // Note: Outlook no longer raises this event. If you have code that 
                            //    must run when Outlook shuts down, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=506785
                        }
           
            #region VSTO generated code

            /// <summary>
            /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
            /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
            /// </summary>
            private void InternalStartup()
                        {
                this.Startup += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Startup);
                this.Shutdown += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Shutdown);
                        }
           
            return 0;
            #endregion
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why do you need to use the `Main` method inside a VSTO add-in?

Comment: I am not sure, what do I use to replace it?

Comment: Typically the `Startup` method of the `ThisAddin` class is called when the add-in is started (see `ThisAddIn_Startup` in your code).

Comment: So should I place all the code I have under Main and place it under ThisAddIn_Startup, and then remove the Main?

Comment: Your code will not be run if you don't use add-in's event handlers.

Comment: And why does it need to be an addin? Is resolving names the only thing it does?

Comment: Yes, it just needs to look up the names in Outlook from that textfile to give me a true or false match

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you need to call `Application.Session.CreateRecipient` / `Recipient.Resolve`. If `Recipient.Resolve` returns true, the name is resolved and can be used to send an email to. Note than anything that looks like an SMTP address (`"something@whatever.blah"`) will be resolved to a one-off recipient even if it is not in the Outlook address book.

Something along the lines of

```
Recipient recip = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Session.CreateRecipient(line);
if (recip.Resolve())
{
    //the name in the line variable can be resolved 
}
```

Comment: How do I call  Application.Session.CreateRecipient? I am very new to programming so I do not understand where to input that in the code.

Comment: See the updated answer above.

Answer (score 0):

The [NameSpace.CreateRecipient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.createrecipient) method creates a `Recipient` object. The name of the recipient can be a string representing the display name, the alias, or the full SMTP email address of the recipient. This method is most commonly used to create a Recipient object for use with the `GetSharedDefaultFolder` method, for example, to open a delegator's folder. It can also be used to verify a given name against an address book like in your scenario.

To make sure that such name exists in the address book you need to use the [Recipient.Resolve](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.recipient.resolve) method. It attempts to resolve a `Recipient` object against the Address Book and returns true if the object was resolved; otherwise, false. So, if it returns false - there is no such record in Outlook for a given name.

```
var recip = session.CreateRecipient("Eugene Astafiev");
if(recip.Resolve())
{
   // the entry was found in outlook
}
else
{
  // the specified person was not found in the Outlook's address book
}
```

Comment: Where would the NameSpace go in the code. I am confused

Comment: You can use the `GetNamespace("MAPI")` method or the `Session` property to retrieve the Namespace class instance.

Comment: I am still having problems incorporating the Namespace.

Comment: Please check the updated post with a sample code.